# Find values in a string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have a file with lines of string. Each line represent a collection of key value, for example:

```
Name=JUI;Type=HomeUser;Address=Belgium;Address=Liege;Address=Street
Name=Tim;Type=HomeUser;Address=Belgium;Address=Hasselt;Address=Street
Name=Kim;Type=Proff;Address=Germany;Address=Dusseldorf;Address=Street
Name=Ils;Type=Proff;Address=Germany;Address=Munich;Address=Street
Name=Jan;Type=Student;Address=Germany;Address=Frankfurt;Address=Street
Name=Dav;Type=Student;Address=France;Address=Mitz;Address=Street
Name=Soli;Type=HomeUser;Address=France;Address=Lyon;Address=Street
Name=Mik;Type=HomeUser;Address=Switzerland;Address=Zurich;Address=Street
Name=Peter;Type=Blocked;Address=Netherland;Address=Enschede;Address=Street 
Name=Maz;Type=Blocked;Address=Germany;Address=Achen;Address=Street
Name=Jo;Type=Teacher;Address=Belgium;Address=Antwerpen;Address=Street
```

How can I do the following:

1. Get the names where type is HomeUser
2. Get the types where Address =Germany (problem there are 3 address key in earch line)
3. Get the name where address =Lyon

Is there is a simple way to do that?

Comment: There is way more information needed here than just a bunch of assignments. Are these strings, ints, enums, classes...? Are these supposed to properties of a class? There is absolutely no way to answer this without knowing what we're even looking at. How is is this data being pulled into C# and utilized?

Comment: I apologize allow me to be more concise as to what I mean. What I mean is there are probably 100 or more different methods of parsing data from a file. What I mean is if you want the best way to do it in your specific case, more information about the data, where it's going, and where it's coming from should be supplied.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger The data coming from a log filegoing to sql table some tables are defined. An example: I extract all users names **Name=?**
where country is Switzerland in the case i show in my post i should get **Mik** then update his record in the database. My main issue is that there are 3 keys with the name **Address**

Comment: Do you have any control over the way the log file is written to the file? Is it possible to have it export to something better structured like XML?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger No i don't we get this file from external company

Comment: In that case then my vote would have to be with John Skeet's answer below... if I had a dollar for every time I said that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *all* of these cases, the answer is really simple when you've got a better data representation - you can just use LINQ.

However, the first step will be to parse the data. Model it *something* like this:

```
public class User // ???
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; } // Should this be an enum?
    public IList<string> Addresses { get; private set; }

    // Could make this a constructor if you really want... I like the
    // explicit nature of the static factory method.
    public static User ParseLine(string line)
    {
        // TODO: Split line into components etc
    }
}
```

One you've got a `List<User>` your queries will be really easy - but it's important to separate "put data into a more natural representation" from "do interesting operations with data".

This is a much more general point than just this particular example, but always try to get your data into a natural, useful representation as early as you can, and then keep it in that representation for as long as you can. Only deal with an awkward representation (typically a string) at the boundaries of your code, if possible.

Comment: Thank you! one more question, do you think if create an object for each line in the file of the class User will reduce application performance or increase memory usage? Let us say there are around 2 Million line ==> 2 million object of class User will be created

Comment: @Maro: Well yes, it will increase memory usage - but if you start off with clear, readable code it's *much* easier to optimize in a targeted way later, than if you write your code assuming that you need to optimize everywhere. Just how many lines are you going to read? Do you have to have all the values in memory at once? (Perhaps you could stream them, for example.)

Comment: I will read multiple file Total lines around 19 Million.
I have to process most +/- 95% the rest will be ignored.

Comment: @Maro: Just because you have to process them doesn't mean you need to have all of them in memory simultaneously, necessarily. At the very least, I would create a `User` class which could *later* potentially hold the data in just a string, exposing it as properties by parsing on-the-fly. Provide a clean API, and optimize within the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Regex to parse the item: `"Name=(.+?);Type=(.+?);Address=(.+?) etc."`
Then you could create a class to hold all the information

```
class Record { public string Name; public string Type; public string Address; public string Address2; public string Address3}
```

then match each line with the regex, fill the fields from Match groups and create an instance of the class and add these to a `List<Record> records`.

Now you can easily search with linq for:

1. type is HomeUser : records.Where(p=>p.Type=="HomeUser")
2. Address is Germany : records.Where(p=>p.Address=="Germany")
3. Address is Lyon: records.Where(p=>p.Address=="Lyon")

you could easily extend this example to look in all 3 address fields

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to first define a struct

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public string Name, Type /* etc.*/ ;
}
```

After that you'll need to split your input

```
string[] arrayOfInputs = inpuString.Split(new char[]{Environment.NewLine, '\n', '\r'}) // splits your input, such that every element represents a line
List<MyStruct> myStruct = new List<MyStruct>;
foreach (string s in arrayOfInputs)
{
    string[] arrayOfFields = s.Split(';');
    // arrayOfFields[0] == "Name=name"
    // arrayOfFields[1] == "Type=type"
    // etc. extract needed info
    myStruct.Add(new MyStruct(/* arguments go here */))
}
```

Now that you have extracted your data and put them into a list of structs, you may search for the required data using Linq

```
string theNameImLookingFor = from element in myStruct
                             where element.Type == "HomeUser"
                                || element.Address[0] == "Lyon"
                                || element.Address[1] == "Lyon"
                                || element.Address[2] == "Lyon"
                             select element.Name;

string theTypeImLookingFor = from element in myStruct
                             // etc.
                             select element.Type;
```

Alternatively you can do it like this:

```
string tNILF = myStruct.Where(element => element.Type == "HomeUser" /* || etc. */).Select(element => element.Name);
```

Comment: Imagin i have 2 million lines if i create a struct for each line then i must upgrade the server memory :-) according to my information Structs are value type :-)

Comment: @Maro In that case it would be better to process only one line at a time, thus LINQ becomes useless. To get each line, you'll use a Regex `foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"name=.+?((?=name=)|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) { /* match.Value contains a single line, which you can split by ';' to get each field */ }` However, in case the Regex doesn't behave as intended, debugging will become a major pain. You have been warned ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to read the key-value pairs into a collection of dynamic objects. Once this is done, you can use the dynamic runtime to query the dynamic objects using LINQ:

To create a collection of dynamic objects:

```
var users = str.Split("\r\n".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Split(';')
                    .Select(p => p.Split('='))
                    .ToLookup(s => s[0], s => s[1])
                    .ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => (l.Count() > 1) 
                        ? (object)l.ToList() : (object)l.First())
                    .ToExpando());
```

Note the use of this extension method:

```
public static dynamic ToExpando(this IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var kv in dict)
        expando[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
    return expando;
}
```

Then you can run the queries you're interested in:

1.Get the names where type is HomeUser:

```
var homeUsers = users.Where(u => u.Type == "HomeUser")
    .Select(u => u.Name);
```

2.Get the types where Address =Germany (Note: `.Address` is a `List<string>`):

```
var typesInGermany = users.Where(u=>u.Address.Contains("Germany"))
    .Select(u => u.Type).Distinct();
```

3.Get the name where address =Lyon:

```
var namesInLyon = users.Where(u => u.Address.Contains("Lyon"))
    .Select(u => u.Name);
```